# Material-UI Drawer rounding off corners leaves whitespace

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, typescript, material-ui

I'm using the drawer from Material UI and I'm trying to round the corners using CSS like so:

```
  style={{
    borderRadius: "25px",
    backgroundColor: "red",
    overflow: "hidden",
    padding: "300px"
  }}
```

It works kinda, but the actual corners remain white instead of transparent.

[image: https://i.gyazo.com/e85a9c66d8ac70e90f36937c5f47395e.png]

How can I fix it such that the corners are properly rounded off? I've put my code in the following codesandbox:

https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-q3n14

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## Reason

Your `SwipeableDrawer` wraps your content inside a `<Paper />` component. A Materiaul-UI paper component has shadows and a non-transparent background.

## Solution

You do not use classnames, you use style, so the right way would be to set the SwipeableDrawer paperProps to:

```
PaperProps={{ elevation: 0, style: { backgroundColor: "transparent" } }}
```

- Elevation: 0, so that there are no shadows anymore
- backgroundColor: 'transparent', so that there is no background except yours

PS: Instead of having your borderRadius on your div, you may set it on the paper itself using the same prop

```
PaperProps={{ square: false }}
```

And remove your borderRadius from your div

## Using classNames

If you used classNames ([doc](https://material-ui.com/customization/components/)), you could have set the paper className to one of yours, using the `classes` prop:

```
classes={{ paper: classes.someClassName }}
```